# Generating a Form for Each User Checked in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

I'm working on a scheduling form where a User would check a box for each user that they would like to create a schedule for on a given day.  As of right now, a checkbox is generated for each user and upon submission, the application will replicate the selected schedule for each user selected.

```
<%= form_for @workday do |f| %>
<br/>
<% User.all.each do |user| %>
    <%= f.check_box "id", {multiple: true}, user.id %>
    <%= user.full_name %>
    
<% end %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %>
    <%= f.date_field :date %>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_time %>
    <%= f.select :start_hour, ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]%>
    <%= ":" %>
    <%= f.select :start_min, ["00", "15", "30", "45"] %>
    <%= f.select :start_am_or_pm, ["AM", "PM"] %>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_time %>
    <%= f.select :end_hour, ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]%>
    <%= ":" %>
    <%= f.select :end_min, ["00", "15", "30", "45"] %>
    <%= f.select :end_am_or_pm, ["AM", "PM"] %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add Schedule Event" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

What I would like to have happen instead is that an individual form would be created for each User checkbox that is selected.  This way multiple and unique schedules can be created for the same given day.  Any thoughts or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should consider a user form , not a workday form, since size of User.all has growing room but workday not, right ? create some typical workday something like nine-to-five, ... then you can set that workday default for all user in model logic (no need on form), and  in case you want set a special workday for some users, let create group_of_user association then in form you just need 2 fields: group_user and special_workday, that's it, you will query group users and set workday for each of them in model logic.

Comment: in case you keen to add dynamic nested forms, this gem maybe help: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form, or if you don't want to use gem, this also maybe help: https://stevepolito.design/blog/create-a-nested-form-in-rails-from-scratch/, i just recommend that it's better user field is a search field (e.g. search user by name), something like select2: https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails, not a list of checkboxes for all users.